# select specific columns from linq to sql code and session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, linq-to-sql

i trying to create an shopping cart using session . how select the selected fields to displays in cart in other page from the linq to mysql code.

I have tried this code:

```
if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            using (ShoppingDataContext data = new ShoppingDataContext())
            {
                List<int> Cart = (List<int>)Session["Cart"];
                var Products = data.Products.Where(Product => Cart.Contains(Product.ProductID)).Select(Product => Product.ProductName && Product.ProductUnitPrice)) ;
                GridViewProduct.DataSource = Products;
                GridViewProduct.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [formulate projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386978%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `new` to select the attributes you want and return a new projected type or a user defined type (class) object.

```
var Products = data.Products.Where(Product => Cart.
                        Contains(Product.ProductID)).
                        Select(Product => new {
                                ProductName = Product.ProductName ,
                                ProductUnitPrice = Product.ProductUnitPrice
                        })) ;
```

You can make object of your class.

```
var Products = data.Products.Where(Product => Cart.
                        Contains(Product.ProductID)).
                        Select(Product => new YourClass{
                                ProductName = Product.ProductName ,
                                ProductUnitPrice = Product.ProductUnitPrice
                        })) ;
```